# Is "In case of the developments in medical research..." grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, conditional-constructions, grammaticality-in-context

> **In case of** the developments in medical research, many patients would have died.

My textbook presented three other alternatives:

> **If it weren't for**…
>
> **Without**…
>
> **Unless**…

and said that **in case of** is correct. However, **in case of** seems unsuitable to me.

The correct form I can think of is:

> **If it hadn't been for** the developments...

Comment: The quote by itself doesn't make logical sense, but it might in context. Could you add additional context before and after your quote? From a grammar point of view, the first part should be "In the case of developments...".

Comment: this was actually a choose the correct answer question, and it was (In case of - If it weren't for - Without - unless) and the answer was in case of

Comment: Have to disagree. I would go with: "*If it weren't for* the developments in medical research, many patients would have died." You should add the multiple choices to your question.

Comment: yes but the answer is wrong which made me question the logic behind it

Comment: The common usage of "in case of" is in cause and effect phrases. For example, "In case of fire, break glass." or "In case of hot weather, be sure to drink plenty of water." "in case of" doesn't make sense in your example phrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your choices of

> In case of
>   If it weren't for
>   Without
>   Unless

The only choices which make sense are

> *If it weren't for* the developments in medical research
>   *Without* the developments in medical research

Using

> *In case of* the developments in medical research

would mean "in the event that development in medical research happens", not that it already *has* happened, which is a prerequisite for "lives to be saved".

Which textbook are you using?

Comment: my school's textbook

Comment: @bigworld12 Peter is right and your textbook is wrong. :) Actually, to be fair, can you post some of the surrounding text from the textbook? We might all be misunderstanding the textbook's question.

Comment: it's in a collective exam, there is no context and this is just the bare question.

Comment: also does this sentence include if's 3rd condition? because then if it weren't for would be grammatically wrong, or I am missing something?

Comment: @bigworld12 In that case, Peter is right and the textbook is wrong. What is the name of the textbook and what country is it used in?

Comment: Longman for secondary grade, it's used in Egypt, and the collective exam is on the official moe site (http://moe.gov.eg/exams_2016/namazeg2015-2016/English_sec3_%20model4_2016.pdf) (Question 3 -  10). answer is right after the exam

Comment: @bigworld12 I just checked the other answers for question 3. 3–9 can be (a) or (d), not just (a). It depends on the time the speaker is referring to. 3–10 can be (a) or (c), but not (b). 3–12 can be (b) or (c), depending on what kind of expert Naguib Mahfouz is, though (c) is much, much more likely, so this error is not serious. If Mahfouz is very good at _using_ Egyptian culture somehow, then he is an expert "with" Egyptian culture. [Example](https://www.google.com/?#q=%22expert+with+culture%22&tbm=bks). There is a typo in 3–3: it should say _Farah's_, not _Farah_. All the others are correct.

Comment: @bigworld12 One other note: regarding 3–2, it's very unusual, at least in contemporary English, to refer to a woman in her 30s as a woman "in the fourth decade". Even if you wanted to speak of decades (which is unusual), you would word it "in **her** fourth decade". However, "in the fourth decade" is grammatically correct—just very unusual.

Comment: looks like they are teaching us wrong English :P

Comment: #11 should be "will buy" not "might buy" since a "promise" usually means one *will* do something, using "might buy" does not require "promise" since they might or might not anyway without promising, without "promise" either is correct.

Comment: @bigworld12 Oops, I missed the error that Peter's previous comment just caught! As Peter says, 3–11 should be (b), not (a). Errors in the teaching of English are very common in most of the world. Often to pass an exam you must give false answers in order to be marked correct.

Comment: this sucks, I don't even know what to trust anymore and this is frustrating

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you could say it that way.  There is some sort implied negative in the first part that isn't correctly expressed using *in case of* in your example.  Reasonable alternatives include:

- If not for (the) developments in medical research, many patients would have died.
- But for (the) developments in medical research, many patients would have died.
- Barring (the) developments in medical research, many patients would have died.
- Except for (the) developments in medical research, many patients would have died.
- Save for (the) developments in medical research, many patients would have died.
- If it weren’t for the developments in medical research, many patients would have died.
- If it hadn’t been for the developments in medical research, many patients would have died.

All of those could also swap around to have the condition clause (the protasis) following the consequence clause (the apodosis):

- Many patients would have died if not for (the) developments in medical research.
- Many patients would have died but for (the) developments in medical research.
- Many patients would have died barring (the) developments in medical research, .
- Many patients would have died except for (the) developments in medical research.
- Many patients would have died save for (the) developments in medical research.
- Many patients would have died if it weren’t for the developments in medical research.
- Many patients would have died if it hadn’t been for the developments in medical research.

Comment: this was actually a choose the correct answer question, and it was (In case of - If it weren't for - Without - unless) and the answer was in case of